# How to pass value from popup window's textboxes to a certain row of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

On my webpage I have a to-do list table where library employees can write down and note the tasks they have to do (shown below):
[image]
Here is my table code:

```
        </div>
            <table id="myTable" class="display table-auto">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>To Clean Booksheleves</td>
                        <td>On 20th November</td>
                        <td><button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                Delete
                            </button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>To Prepare Books Based on Category</td>
                        <td>on 25th November</td>
                        <td><button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                Delete
                            </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have an "Add" button. When employees click on this "Add" button, there will be a popup window where they can input the name of new tasks and also the notes. Here is its code:

(HTML & CSS):

```
<button style="background-color: #555; color: white; padding: 16px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.8;
            position: fixed; bottom: 23px; right: 28px; width: 280px;" onclick="Popup()">Add</button>
        <div style="display: none; position: fixed;bottom: 0; right: 15px; border: 3px solid #f1f1f1; z-index: 9;" id="myForm">
        <form action="/action_page.php" style="max-width: 300px; padding: 10px; background-color: white;">
            <h1>Add Tasks</h1>

            <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Tasks" name="task" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Notes" name="note">

            <button type="submit" style="background-color: #04AA6D; color: white; padding: 16px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%; margin-bottom:10px; opacity: 0.8;">Login</button>
            <button type="button" style=" background-color: red;" onclick="closePopUp()">Close</button>
        </form>
```

(Script):

```
script>
        function Popup() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closePopup() {
             document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
        }
        
    </script>
```

Simply, what should I do to pass value from textboxes in the popup window to the to-do list table? Another word, what should I do to add a new row to the to-do list table by using input from the popup window textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Click of the Submit button, Just Get Access to form data & generate UI Dynamically as shown below.

```js
function Popup() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closePopUp() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

// Event For Submit Button
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // Prevent From Redirection (Default Submit Behaviour)
  e.preventDefault();

  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const task = formData.get("task");
  const note = formData.get("note");

  // Add New Table Row only if Some Data is Available
  if (task !== "" && note !== "") {
    const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = `
 <td>${task}</td>
 <td>${note}</td>
 <td><button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
     Delete
  </button></td>
`;
    tbody.append(tr);

    // Reset the Form to Clear existing Data from Input Fields
    form.reset();
  }

  // Close The Pop Up after Adding.
  closePopUp();

});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  </div>
  <table id="myTable" class="display table-auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>To Clean Booksheleves</td>
        <td>On 20th November</td>
        <td><button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                Delete
                            </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>To Prepare Books Based on Category</td>
        <td>on 25th November</td>
        <td><button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                Delete
                            </button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>

  <button style="background-color: #555; color: white; padding: 16px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.8;
            position: fixed; bottom: 23px; right: 28px; width: 280px;" onclick="Popup()">Add</button>
  <div style="display: none; position: fixed;bottom: 0; right: 15px; border: 3px solid #f1f1f1; z-index: 9;" id="myForm">
    <form id="form" action="/action_page.php" style="max-width: 300px; padding: 10px; background-color: white;">
      <h1>Add Tasks</h1>

      <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Tasks" name="task" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Notes" name="note">

      <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" style="background-color: #04AA6D; color: white; padding: 16px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%; margin-bottom:10px; opacity: 0.8;">Login</button>
      <button type="button" style=" background-color: red;" onclick="closePopUp()">Close</button>
    </form>
</body>
```